# Установить apach с обновлением версий php

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, установка

В Убунте установлен php версии 7.0 и ни как не хочет обновляться. Мне для Apache и jooml-ы требуется 7.2, но я хочу последнюю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там версия php - 8 и 8.1, а по команде установить самую последнюю версию - мне сообщается - что 7.0 последняя и она у меня установлена. Чё за нафик? Как установить последнюю (8.1) версию?

Comment: Какая версия ubuntu?

Comment: Версия: 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Ну значит установите 22.04 наверное?

Comment: Да - была предустановлена на VPS, надо менять...
А не подскажите - там, если я обычную скачиваю - она с рабочим столом ставится - а мнеж не надо! - что ненагружал... тока через терминал собираюсь работать... - как урезать? Там при установке предлагается набор: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_19kb.1661094970.jpg - оно? Мне надо хостинг, apache, joomla - какой набор заказать?

Comment: Ну так не десктопную, а серверную версию устанавливайте, наверное? В официальной серверной версии такой менюшки, которую вы показали на скриншоте, вообще не существует

Comment: А это: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_14kb.1661103376.jpg - что значит?
- по два знакомста - где маска требует по три (255)
и дробь и два знакоместа - там что?

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Я тоже подумал что это маска - но я не могу ввести её как обычно. Сейчас у меня так:
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_27kb.1661104453.jpg
И я не найду нормального описания - почему так. Это улучшилось - когда я ввёл поисковик google.com - мне стали доступны трёхзнаяные поля (255).

Comment: `217.107.217.0/24`

Comment: И «домены поиска» это не то что вы подумали (и заполнять их по-моему нет смысла, я никогда не заполняю)

Comment: Сработало.
Ох.. - ну откудаб я это знал...

Спасибо.